# React Native Flatlist scrolls down when an item from top is removed

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
        <FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={item => this.renderItem(item)}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        refreshControl={<RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
        />
```

I have a FlatList as presented. The data is a timetable and refreshed every minute, the data change occurs when the current time passes an item in the timetable (the item(s) gets removed if they are in the past).

If I scroll down a bit, and as a result of update if an item gets removed from the top of the list, the scroll position stays the same, but since an item got removed from the top, the viewpoint scrolls up a bit.

Is there an easy way of fixing this or should I have some fancy listeners there and around?

Comment: Add a key for the renderItem

Comment: @Raymond isn't keyExtractor for that purpose?